# Jquery and Javascript not returning actual value of display style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple javascript code which sets a div's display = "block" then display="" (an empty value) but when I try to get value of display style using both Jquery and native javascript, both returns value as "block" after resetting it to a blank value. 
How can I get the proper value(blank value) using any of these two?

I need to set it to blank instead of 'none', as it has been used in the product at thousands of places.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getDivStyle(){
            var myDiv = document.getElementById("testDiv");
            var before = $('#testDiv').css('display');
            $('#testDiv').css('display', '');
            var after = $('#testDiv').css('display');
            var computed = getComputedStyle(myDiv).getPropertyValue("display");
            console.log("before-> " + before +"  ----  after-> "+ after+"  ---- computed-> " + computed);
    };
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="testDiv" style="display:block; height:100px; width:500px; border: 1px solid red;">
    test div
    </div>
    <input value="get style" type="button" onclick="getDivStyle()"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Block is the default display.

Comment: But if I set display=" " , and ask for a value, it should return me a blank value.

Comment: No, the `display` setting (as with all CSS properties) has to have a value, it cannot be blank. More info at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

Comment: Because the default `display` on `<div>` is `block`, you can change `<div>` to `<span>` then you can see the difference.

Comment: how could css property value blank

Comment: @Aabid He use jquery,  so `.css('dislay', '')` remove the display property and make the div use its inherited display.

Comment: A div is an HTML block element anyway; you can't just make it nothing. You can use span if you want it to be inline. (Mind that you can't use block elements within span, even when defining block).

Comment: blank is not a valid value of display... so it reverts to the default value which is display for a block element

Comment: if you use span instead of div, after setting to blank it will return inline

Comment: Initially elements have a display="block" and when we are setting it to blank, it behaves like a display="none". Agreed that it should have a value, but in debugger, element.style.display gives me a blank value and these APIs don't. I think I answered my question. :-) .. I need to do a element.style.display. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Regardless of the display value, if you want to show/hide an element using jQuery, you should use the `show()` and `hide()` methods respectively.

Comment: @ManasAndhare `.css('display', '')` dosent set its display to `none`, go check [$.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-value).

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, using show / hide with jQuery corresponds to setting .css({display: block/none)};

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - I am aware of these methods to hide elements, but needed help on getting a blank value as that is the way our product is working. Appreciate the comments. Thanks a lot. Issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, as per all the comments above, the proper way to set turn off display is to set display = "none". But in this case, if it is set to a blank value to get the value we can use

```
element.style.display;
```

as this returns a blank value.

Answer (score 0):

The Syntax for display is

`display: value;`

If you do not want your element to be displayed then you need to change it to `none` or any other value you want. If you set it to blank then it will take the default value.

Edit:

This seems to work

`document.getElementById("testDiv").style.display`

Comment: Thanks, though we can set it to blank and turn off the display. So in my case, i need to use element.style.display to get a blank. Not a proper way to set the display, but I am helpless, that is how the application is running for years.

Comment: When i tried with this `document.getElementById("testDiv").style.display` it is giving me the value as blank in FF and Chrome. May be you could try with this.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for and just answered as well.